# Springboot application throws NoClassDefFound exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following error while running a Restful web service application on spring tool suite using `cxf-jaxrs`, spring boot and maven.

I am using following :-

```
STS-3.9.0 release
jdk-1.8.0-25

Eclipse - oxygen
```

**Log:** Please find the complete log.

> ```
>  .   ____          _            __ _ _
>  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
> ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
>  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
>   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
>  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
>  :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.13.RELEASE)
>
> 2018-05-12 21:00:20.545  INFO 7832 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on
> ```
>
> D1Y89H52 with PID 7832
>   (C:\Users\monika\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE\demo\target\classes
>   started by monika in
>   C:\Users\monika\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE\demo)
>       2018-05-12 21:00:20.549  INFO 7832 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default
>       2018-05-12 21:00:20.608  INFO 7832 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2bea5ab4:
>   startup date [Sat May 12 21:00:20 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>       2018-05-12 21:00:20.636 ERROR 7832 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>   -2018-05-1221:00:20.545INFO7832---[main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication:StartingDemoApplication
>   onD1Y89H52withPID7832
>   (C:\Users\monika\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE\demo\target\classes
>   startedbymonikain
>   C:\Users\monika\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE\demo)
>   2018-05-1221:00:20.549INFO7832---[main]
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication:Noactiveprofileset,
>   fallingbacktodefaultprofiles:default2018-05-1221:00:20.608
>   INFO7832---[main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2bea5ab4:
>   startupdate[SatMay1221:00:20IST2018];rootofcontext
>   hierarchy2018-05-1221:00:20.636ERROR7832---[main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication:Applicationstartupfailed
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/expression/ParserContext  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(NativeMethod)~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(UnknownSource)~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(UnknownSource)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   atjava.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)~[na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(UnknownSource)~[na:1.8.0_102]
>     atjava.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(UnknownSource)~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(UnknownSource)~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(NativeMethod)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   atjava.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(UnknownSource)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   atjava.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(UnknownSource)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(UnknownSource)~
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:69)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
>     atorg.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]   at
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.expression.ParserContext  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   ... 21 common frames omitted 2018-05-12 21:00:20.638 
>   INFO 7832 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext :
>   Closing
>          org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2bea5ab4:
>          startup date [Sat May 12 21:00:20 IST 2018]; root of context

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `spring-expression` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>whatever ver. is comatible with your ver. of spring boot</version>
</dependency>
```

or alternatively

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which may bring in the missing dependency.